# Assigning a string array to keyof T array compiles successfully

Tags: typescript

Given the following code:

```
 class Entity {
   public id: string;
 }
 
 declare function select<T>(fun: (arg: T) => any, arg: T): any;
 
 declare function selector(arg: (keyof Entity)[]): any;
```

I would expect the following code to fail with some error like `Type '"name"' is not assignable to type 'keyof Entity'`, however it seams to compile without an error.

```
 select(selector, ['name']);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: reproducing with typescript 4.3.2 throws an error: `Type '"name"' is not assignable to type '"id"'.ts(2322)`

Comment: It does throw an error in TypeScript v4.3.4: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQYwNghgzlwKIDsAuBLJBPYBvAUMfADgK4BGYKIwKAJgFzBRIBOKCA5gNx4C+ee1AU3AQmA4ADMiCEKgD2CBgLBCkAHgAqAPgAUkhPW0i29dQEpgAXk3AICdABobTY8DP1b6LsH5DIoiVIyKPKKyjKyTIbOBgDWAuiy4vDIaOimANoAuqbudlx4UEoq2oVhSBGO6QDkCBAAtgJV2RxAA)

Comment: `@Heretic Monkey` do you think it has to do with my TypeScript configuration?

Comment: @RafiHenig Note that I was not informed of your reply because you formatted the @ symbol and my username as code. Just type @ and the first three letters or so of the user name, then Tab. It will autofill the rest for you. As far as your question, yes, you are most likely using an older version of TypeScript.

Comment: @HereticMonkey  Thank you for explaining how to reply correctly,  I'm currently using TypeScript 4.3, I suspect it has nothing to do with the TypeScript version as I tried switching to older versions (3 and 2) using the playground in posted and yet an error messages appeared.